# can you use pythagoras on a non right angled triangle

Tags: trigonometry

Sorry I'm a bit confuse, are you allow to use Pythagoras in a non right angled triangle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Pythagorean theorem is a restriction of the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).  Given triangle ABC with sides $a,b,c$ opposite the corresponding angles we have 
$$a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc\cos A$$
As $\cos 90^\circ=0$ the last term drops out in a right triangle.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @MERcurialKG You might not have learnt the law of cosines yet, but it's like the Pythagorean theorem for non-right angled triangles.

Answer (score 0):

No, you [can't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem).

If that were the case, then an equilateral triangle with sides $1, 1, 1$ would have $1^2 = 1^2 + 1^2$, which is not true.

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!